# Как импортировать файл Javascript в Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

изучаю Nuxt.js пытаюсь подключить файл js прописал в nuxt.config.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в консоли показывает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**подкиньте идею как правильно сделать**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Клади в папку `/static`, перед указанием пути не нужно писать `/static/`, то есть в твоём случае будет так:

```
src: '/js/nav.js'
```

Вот [ссылка](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/) на документацию.